# React-Table column fixed width spoils whole table

Tags: css, reactjs, html-table, flexbox, react-table

Can someone explain this to me why i cant set fixed width on **First Name** column?It's setting passed width but it spoils whole table.If you tinker with resizing(by mouse) the column other columns will appear.Is this due to flebox?Im not familiar with flexbox.

```js
var ReactTable = ReactTable.default
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "Name",
              columns: [
                {
                  width:'50',
                  Header: "First Name",
                  accessor: "firstName"
                },
                {
                  Header: "Last Name",
                  id: "lastName",
                  accessor: d => d.lastName
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: "Info",
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "Age",
                  accessor: "age"
                },
                {
                  Header: "Status",
                  accessor: "status"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: 'Stats',
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "Visits",
                  accessor: "visits"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        <br />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.5.3/react-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.5.3/react-table.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

If anyone can add `react-table` to the tags i will be glad.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know much about react-table, but try to not use quotes

```js
var ReactTable = ReactTable.default
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "Name",
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "First Name",
                  accessor: "firstName",
                  width: 50
                },
                {
                  Header: "Last Name",
                  id: "lastName",
                  accessor: d => d.lastName
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: "Info",
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "Age",
                  accessor: "age"
                },
                {
                  Header: "Status",
                  accessor: "status"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: 'Stats',
              columns: [
                {
                  Header: "Visits",
                  accessor: "visits"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        <br />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.5.3/react-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.5.3/react-table.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thats strange,im sure i did try that!Maybe i refreshed page before compiling ended.Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about `react-table`, but you can solve this by setting `width` to all the columns.

```js
var ReactTable = ReactTable.default
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={data}
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "Name",
              columns: [
                {
                  width:'50',
                  Header: "First Name",
                  accessor: "firstName"
                },
                {
                  width:'100',
                  Header: "Last Name",
                  id: "lastName",
                  accessor: d => d.lastName
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: "Info",
              columns: [
                {
                  width:'100',
                  Header: "Age",
                  accessor: "age"
                },
                {
                  width:'100',
                  Header: "Status",
                  accessor: "status"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              Header: 'Stats',
              columns: [
                {
                  width:'100',
                  Header: "Visits",
                  accessor: "visits"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        <br />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.5.3/react-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.5.3/react-table.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: That would do it but i want rest columns to have dynamic width,thanks anyway.